# Beta app promoted to production by mistake, can I go back to open beta in google developer console

Tags: google-play, apk, google-play-console, google-developers-console, developer-console

I was using open beta testing (Early Access) but by mistake I uploaded APK on production and published, can I go back to open beta testing?

Comment: Might be best to contact GooglePlay support about this

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks !

Comment: @Regis_AG .. no there is no solution I found.. only you can unpublish it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

Unpublishing the app will also remove the availability of the app in Beta.

You will need to publish another APK to Production to remove this one. By setting a low maxSdkVersion or a high minSdkVersion or some more constraints in the manifest that affect the availability of the app, you may possibly manage to limit the number of users who would be able to install it.

Comment: Thanks. But does it mean that the users that have a phone compatible only with the beta version will see the app only in 'early access' (that is to say without rating and comments on the store) Thanks.